# How to run alias that is defined in ~/.bashrc within rc.local?

Tags: linux, alias

I define alias inside my ~/.bashrc file. That alias includes many commands including "git pull". The name of the alias is 'go'

I put this "go" command inside the /etc/rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo touch /var/lock/subsys/local
sudo /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
sudo redis-server /etc/redis.conf
source ~/.bashrc
go
```

However, this go command it not executed. I check by changing go to "git pull" and it works when the instance get started.

How come I enable this alias to be called inside the rc.local?

Can you share your thought on it?

Looking forward to seeing your ideas!

Comment: My recommendation: **Don't do that**. Type the entire command in `rc.local` (use a good editor, e.g. [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)...) - you want to keep that file readable

Comment: Try setting the full path instead of ~/. The home directory alias is not available without a user. And to second the previous comment better use the command itself with full paths

Comment: You want to run a user command on `/etc/rc.local`? You do understand that `source ~/.bashrc` is reading `/root/.bashrc` (I hope)? Is `/etc/rc.local` executed on your machine _at all_? Nowadays (systemd) `/etc/rc.local` is just ignored, nothing uses it. Also `The name of the alias is 'go'` is a bad name if you ever would want to install [go](https://github.com/golang/go). Also, do not run `nginx` nor `redis` nor other services from `/etc/rc.local`, run them as proper services from the system service manager. And, in what directory you want to execute that `git pull`?